# Google Cloud VPN Confusion

Tags: vpn, google-compute-engine, cisco-vpn, gcloud

I have a scenario where I need to connect 1 client company with my GCE via Google VPN. 
My GCE IP address is 10.240.0.3/16 and public IP (lets assume) x.x.x.x
now the client requirement is they need public  IP on GCE directly, instead of Private IP .As per their policy since there are chances that private IP can be similar on multiple customer therefore they does not allow Private IP as encryption domain they only allow public IP.
To clear their requirement more they  need the setup like this.

GCE[Public IP]--------VPN[Public IP]<------------>[Public IP] ClientVPN

now my question is how does it work. How can I assign Public IP directly to GCE. And if not can I share NATed public IP of GCE as direct public IP of it.  Like below.

GCE-[Private IP]---------[NAT][Public IP]------------VPN[public IP]--------------[Public IP]ClientVPN

the main problem is due to the above reason we have no other way out of this instead of fulfilling client requirement. This problem seems like a show stopper to us. kindly guide me and suggest what is your best way out of this situation. I will be very thankful.

Thanks,
Yousuf

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do will work with a VPN that supports Port Address Translation (PAT). [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns) does not support this feature at the moment.

You can configure any open VPN software that supports this feature on a GCE instance. At this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#settingupvpn), you can find an example on how to do this.